# How do I do a Fade/No transition between view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboardsegue

Is it possible to do a fade in and fade out transition between View Controllers in Storyboard. Or without transition.

If it's possible, what's the code for it?

Answer (score 145):

If presenting a modal view controller, you can specify a [`modalTransitionStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621388-modaltransitionstyle) of [`UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle). If doing this with a segue in your storyboard, select the attributes inspector for the segue, and specify the transition style there:

[image]

If presenting the view controller programmatically, you can define your modal segue between the view controllers in your storyboard with a "Transition" of "Cross Dissolve" and then have the source view controller perform this segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"presentSegue" sender:sender];
```

Or, if you are calling `presentViewController`:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryboardID"];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

In iOS 7, Apple has provided a new technology that provides a rich and robust control for highly customized transitions. For more information, refer to WWDC 2013 video [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=218).

But, for instance, if you want to customize the push and pop animations in iOS 7 to fade, you would specify a `delegate` for the navigation controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
}
```

You would then implement `animationControllerForOperation` that specified the animator objects for pushing and popping:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                  animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                               fromViewController:(UIViewController*)fromVC
                                                 toViewController:(UIViewController*)toVC
{
    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush)
        return [[PushAnimator alloc] init];

    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop)
        return [[PopAnimator alloc] init];

    return nil;
}
```

You'd obviously have to implement your custom push and pop animators, such as:

```
@interface PushAnimator : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@end

@implementation PushAnimator

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.5;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController* toViewController   = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];

    toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}

@end
```

And

```
@interface PopAnimator : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@end

@implementation PopAnimator

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.5;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController* toViewController   = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    [[transitionContext containerView] insertSubview:toViewController.view belowSubview:fromViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}

@end
```

There is a similar, but slightly different technique for customizing modal transitions, too (though if you were just doing a face, you'd probably just use the `modalTransitionStyle` discussed above unless there was some other subtle customization you wanted to employ). See the aforementioned [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=218) for more information.

Bottom line, custom transitions for iOS 7 are a slightly complicated, but very robust way to provide tremendous control over the animations for transitions.

Comment: Thank you for making such a complete & copy/paste'able answer!

Answer (score 16):

For creating Custom Segue create subclass of UIStoryboard segue.
For example:

```
// MCFadeSegue.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MCFadeSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end

// MCFadeSegue.m
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "MCFadeSegue.h"

@implementation MCFadeSegue

- (void)perform
{
  CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
  transition.duration = 0.5;
  transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

  [[[[[self sourceViewController] view] window] layer] addAnimation:transition
      forKey:kCATransitionFade];

  [[self sourceViewController]
      presentViewController:[self destinationViewController]
      animated:NO completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Then in MainStoryboard.storyboard choose segue and set Style:Custom and Class:MCFadeSegue.

Comment: should be @ implementation MCFadeSegue not @ implementation MCFadeInSegue   same as .h

Answer (score 9):

Push/Pop UIVIewController FadeIn/FadeOut in Swift

```
class FadeInPushSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    var animated: Bool = true

    override func perform() {

        if var sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as? UIViewController, var destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {

            var transition: CATransition = CATransition()

            transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
            sourceViewController.view.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
            sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)


        }
    }

}

class FadeOutPopSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        if var sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as? UIViewController, var destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {

            var transition: CATransition = CATransition()

            transition.duration = 0.4
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade

            sourceViewController.view.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
            sourceViewController.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this one.

```
    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.4
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcID") as! My_ViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Comment: Very good answer. it helps me a lot after a long time of searching. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Without needing to create a custom segue, I put together this code to present the view...

```
UIViewController *nextView = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_STORYBOARD_NAME"];

nextView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:nil];
// (For a cross dissolve, set animated:YES.  For no transition, set animated:NO.)
```

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this question!

Answer (score 4):

My Swift Version with optional checking offcourse!

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let stView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("STVC") as? STVC {
        stView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
        self.navigationController?.presentViewController(stView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Just make sure to set the Storyboard ID of the "View controller" in IB

Answer (score 3):

Push/Pop UIVIewController FadeIn/FadeOut in **Swift 3** syntax, based on [Eugene Braginets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1624912/eugene-braginets)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31391500/3659227)

```
class FadeInPushSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    var animated: Bool = true

    override func perform() {

        let sourceViewController = self.source
        let destinationViewController = self.destination

        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()

        transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
        sourceViewController.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
        sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)

    }

}

class FadeOutPopSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        let sourceViewController = self.source

        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()

        transition.duration = 0.4
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade

        sourceViewController.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
        _ = sourceViewController.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5:**

After spending hours on finding the right solution [Rob's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10969582/4036390) one answered all of my needs, after a few adjustments it was perfect.

Create the fade View Controller class:

```
class FadeViewControllerTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    
    var fadeOut: Bool = false
    
    func transitionDuration(
        using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        
        if fadeOut {
            animateFadeOut(using: transitionContext)
            return
        }
        
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!
        transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
        toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: { _ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }
    
    func animateFadeOut(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
        transitionContext.containerView.insertSubview(toViewController.view, belowSubview: fromViewController.view)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { _ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }
}
```

In your Navigation Controller's first View Controller:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    private let fadeVCTransition = FadeViewControllerTransition()
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        fadeVCTransition.fadeOut = (operation == .pop)
        return fadeVCTransition
    }
```

And that's it.

Comment: how could i use the fadeVCTransition variable and the navigationController function to perform the fade segue ?

Answer (score 2):

What I did was to use Storyboard in Interface Builder, connected the two viewcontroller you need to move to /from  and back (hold ctrl and drag click from the origin viewcontroller to destination viewcontroller), and changed the segue properties. I used the following:

[image]

I then used the following:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showMovieDetailSegue" sender:self];
```

when you want to remove it, just call this from the origin viewcontroller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Simple and very quick.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me absolutely nuts for several hours. None of these solutions seemed to be what I wanted, and I was losing my mind. Finally came up with the following, which swaps view controllers within a single NSWindow using a fade out/fade in transition. First it performs a fade out, then, in the completion handler, it sets the view for the window to the new view and performs a fade in. Maybe there's a better way to do this, but this is the simplest way I could hack together.

```
class CustomSegue : NSStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        guard let fromController = sourceController as? NSViewController else {
            return;
        }
        guard let toController = destinationController as? NSViewController else {
            return;
        }
        let animationDuration = 0.5;
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({
            $0.duration = animationDuration;
            fromController.view.animator().alphaValue = 0.0;
        }, completionHandler: {
            fromController.view.window?.contentViewController = toController;
            toController.view.alphaValue = 0.0;
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({
                $0.duration = animationDuration;
                toController.view.animator().alphaValue = 1.0;
            })
        });

    }
}
```

The lack of examples in Apple documentation makes me want to tear my brain out, and the mix of Objective C and Swift everywhere is just... bah!

Answer (score 0):

**To present WITHOUT Transition:**

- Select your segue in the Storyboard
- Uncheck "Animates" in the Attributes Inspector

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose an `extension` to `UINavigationController` which is based on @Soumya Ranjan answer:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func addTransition(duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.25,
                       timingFunctionName: CAMediaTimingFunctionName = .easeInEaseOut,
                       type: CATransitionType = .fade,
                       forKey key: String? = nil) {
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = duration
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: timingFunctionName)
        transition.type = type
        view.layer.add(transition, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**
Before setting/pushing new controllers to navigation make sure to call `addTransition()`.

*IMPORTANT:* to set/push new controller with custom transition `animated:` parameter must be set to `false` (see example below)

```
let viewController = UIViewController()

let navigationController = UINavigationController()
navigationController.addTransition() // <--- HERE
navigationController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false) // <--- HERE
```

Also feel free to provide custom parameters:

```
navigationController.addTransition(
    duration: 0.4,
    timingFunctionName: .linear,
    type: .reveal,
    forKey: "CustomTransitionKey"
)
```