# Fade out transition when unwind segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, catransition, unwind-segue

Using storyboard, i unwind a viewcontroller

I'm looking for:

- Remove the left to right transition

And also

- Set a fadeIn fadeOut between the 2 UIViewController.

I'm pretty sure the way to do it is via this:

```
   func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
            return nil
    }
```

But, even is this was called and return nil, i'm still viewing the transition.

Comment: Seems like answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961926/how-do-i-do-a-fade-no-transition-between-view-controllers

Comment: This blog post offers good explanation and solution: http://netsplit.com/custom-ios-segues-transitions-and-animations-the-right-way I'm swift and iOS beginner and I did manage to follow it easily.